# How to get the FIlemaker File| Edit| View bar back

Tags: filemaker

Hey guys for some reason the bar in the photo below vanished. It's not because of a script. How can I get it back?

[image: filemaker bar]

Comment: (1) Not a programming question. (2) Not a reproducible problem.

Comment: A shot in the dark: you may have opened a file that installs a custom menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows platform use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to run script space and create a new script with these two script steps and run it.

1. Install Menu Set ["[Standard FileMaker Menus]"; Use as file default:on]
2. Show/Hide Menubar [Lock:off; Show]

Answer (score -1):

you can get it back from "View" menu , You can have "Status Toolbar" and "Formatting Bar" (i Didn't understand what bar exactly you mean :) ).